# Best method to load from .csv file in a similar manner to MATLAB in C language

Tags: c, matlab, csv, loading

I am trying to convert a MATLAB simulation into C without using the integrated coder, to try and teach myself C. In MATLAB to import and use data from an Excel/ csv file, you either manually import the data using the GUI into the workspace where you can then save as a .mat file and use the variables from there, or the not recommended method is to use "csvread". I am trying to perform a similar operation in C.

I can get data from a csv file (720 rows by 3 columns) using the code below, however i am struggling to pass the data from the `load_PV` function to the `main()` function as the outputted data is a multidimensional array. My main question is if this is the best method and to pursue it, or if i could/should make a function that loads each column individually as a new variable in a loop and pass those to the main() function

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdint.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

float CA[720];
float P[720];
float V[720];
//~ static float ARRAY[720];

float load_PV(int r, int c, float DATA[720][3])
{
  char buf[720];
  //~ static float ARRAY[720];

  FILE *fp = fopen("PV_Data.csv", "r");

  if(!fp)
  {
    printf("Could Not Open File\n");
  }
  int i = 1;

  while(fgets(buf, 720, fp))
  {
    CA[i] = atof(strtok(buf, ","));
    P[i] = atof((strtok(NULL, ",")));
    V[i] = atof((strtok(NULL, ",")));
    DATA[i][1] = CA[i];
    DATA[i][2] = P[i];
    DATA[i][3] = V[i];
    i++;
  }

  //~ printf("%f\n", ARRAY[540][3]);

  return(DATA[720][3]);
}

int main()
{
    int r = 720;
    int c = 3;
    float DATA[r][c];

    float data = load_PV(r, c, DATA[720][3]);

    printf("%f\n", data);

    //~ int i = 1;

    //~ for(i = 1; i<=720; i++);
    //~ {
        //~ printf("%f", data[i][1]);
        //~ printf("\t");
        //~ printf("%f", data[i][2]);
        //~ printf("\t");
        //~ printf("%f\n", data[i][3]);
    //~ }
}
```

I expected as I'm not as familiar with C (can you tell? :P) that the output would just be a 720x3 array of floats, however when compiling I get the following error messages;

```
gcc -Wall -o "Test2" "Test2.c" (in directory: C:\Users\Student\Dropbox\C Projects\MATLAB_to_C)
Test2.c: In function 'main':
Test2.c:47:29: error: incompatible type for argument 3 of 'load_PV'
  float data = load_PV(r, c, DATA[720][3]);
                             ^
Test2.c:11:8: note: expected 'float (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'float'
  float load_PV(int r, int c, float DATA[720][3])
        ^
Compilation failed.
```

I am not as familiar with pointers as they're one of the aspects of C I'm trying to learn, I've seen that you can accomplish this with them, but I didn't completely understand the examples, so haven't used them as I am trying to learn not copy. So is this approach valid or is another more widely used?

P.S. This is not a homework question. I have just graduated from university and have seen that more companies are looking for C than MATLAB so trying to learn for future development. This is a hobby/ professional development exercise

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing syntax for defining/declaring an array and accessing an array.

This is a declaration of a parameter:

```
float DATA[720][3]
```

Here `DATA` is declared to be an array.

This is an access to an array member:

```
return(DATA[720][3]);
```

You are access the element at position `[720][3]` of that array. This is a single element of type `float`. Any you need to be aware that indexing in C starts at 0. This means that index `[720][3]` is an out of bounds access. Maximum range is `[719][2]`.

The same problem occurs when you call that functon:

```
float data = load_PV(r, c, DATA[720][3]);
```

While the function expects to get an array, you only provide 1 single element of another array. Again it is an out of bounds access for that array.

If you want to pass the array, you need to use

```
float data = load_PV(r, c, DATA);
```

You also need to be aware that arrays decay to pointers when passed as parameters. This means when your parameter list looks like this

```
int func(int array[123])
```

the type of `array` is not `int[123]` but only `int*` or `int(*)`. Also `sizeof(array)` is the size of a pointer and not the size of the whole array.

Same for your function:

```
float load_PV(int r, int c, float DATA[720][3])
```

Here the type of the third parameter is not `float[720][3]` but `float(*)[3]`.
Therefore the compiler complaints about a mismatch between expected and passed parameter type:

```
test2.c:11:8: note: expected 'float (*)[3]' but argument is of type 'float'
  float load_PV(int r, int c, float DATA[720][3])
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for replying. I've tried applying your recommendations and the only problem i have is defining the type float(*)[3] for the function as i get an error message saying;

Test2.c:11:40: error: expected ';', ',' or ')' before 'DATA'

I have tried to define it as;

float load_PV(int r, int c, float*[3] DATA)

Comment: You should not change prototype. As I mentioned you need to change your call of that function: `float data = load_PV(r, c, DATA);` Nevertheless I am not sure what the return value means. The result is in `DATA` after the function call.

Comment: ok, i've modified the call as suggested and i can now print an element of the matrix, but not the entire thing. The return aspect was that i was attempting to have the output of "load_PV" as the matrix itself, so when i wrote data = load_PV(), the matrix would be assigned to "data". However after reading I'm not sure if this can work as a function in C cannot output a matrix unless i've read wrong?

Comment: No, this cannot work. You need to return a pointer to the whole matrix. But you don't need to do this. You already have the matrix in `DATA`. What else do you want? And if you want to print the matrix, you need to print each element. A single `printf` call will not do this for you.

Comment: All sorted, i can now print the entire matrix with a loop. This exercise of printing was just to prove what variable contained the data, so i have realised that "DATA" has the matrix stored within it and can be accessed for each element. Last question is that i now have an error saying that the variable "data" is unused, as that is what i have set as the output to load_PV. how can you call a function with a variable as an output without using that output to avoid the error? Thanks

Comment: If you don't intent to use the return value of a function, why do you assign it to a variable? Simply remove the assignment. If the compiler warns about ignoring a function return value, you can add a cast to `void`: `(void)load_PV(r, c, DATA);`

Answer (score 1):

In a first iteration you could write something like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

typedef struct {
    float CA;
    float P;
    float V;
} Entry;


#define ROWS 720

Entry *load_PV() {
    char buf[1024];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("PV_Data.csv", "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("Could Not Open File\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    Entry *entries = malloc(sizeof(Entry) * ROWS);

    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS && fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); i++) {
        entries[i].CA = atof(strtok(buf, ","));
        entries[i].P = atof((strtok(NULL, ",")));
        entries[i].V = atof((strtok(NULL, ",")));
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return entries;
}

int main() {
    Entry *entries = load_PV();
    for (int i = 0; i < ROWS; i++) {
        Entry entry = entries[i];
        printf("%f %f %f\n", entry.CA, entry.P, entry.V);
    }
    free(entries);
    return 0;
}
```

**Changes**

- since each row consists of values CA, P and V we could use a struct
- a define determines the number of rows
- we are allocated dynamically memory for the number of rows
- the FILE* is closed with fclose(fp)

**More Dynamic and Robust Solution**

The above code is a first iteration, but it's probably not as dynamic and robust as you might wish even for a hobby exercise project.

So what should/can be improved:

- the dimensions (number of rows and columns) should be dynamic
- it should handle missing lines in the file
- it should handle missing columns in the file
- the number of read rows should be returned

Then the code could look like this in a second iteration:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


int load_PV(float **dataPtr, int r, int c) {
    char buf[1024];

    FILE *fp;
    if ((fp = fopen("PV_Data.csv", "r")) == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could Not Open File\n");
        exit(-1);
    }

    float *data = calloc(r * c, sizeof(float));
    if (!data) {
        *dataPtr = NULL;
        return 0;
    }
    *dataPtr = data;

    int row = 0;
    for (row = 0; row < r && fgets(buf, sizeof(buf), fp); row++) {
        char *token = strtok(buf, ",");
        if(token) {
            data[row * c] = strtof(token, NULL);
            for (int col = 1; col < c; col++) {
                token = strtok(NULL, ",");
                if(token) {
                    data[row * c + col] = strtof(token, NULL);
                } else {
                    fprintf(stderr, "missing value in row %d\n", row);
                }
            }
        } else {
            fprintf(stderr, "missing value in row %d\n", row);
        }
    }

    fclose(fp);

    return row;
}

int main() {
    int r = 720;
    int c = 3;
    float *data;

    int number_of_Rows = load_PV(&data, r, c);
    for (int i = 0; i < number_of_Rows; i++) {
        float *rowData = &data[i * c];
        printf("[%d]: ", i);
        for(int col = 0; col < c; col++) {
            printf("%f ", rowData[col]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    if(data) {
        free(data);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

So how does it work?

In main there is a pointer with the name data to float. The *address* of this pointer is passed to load_PV together with the dimensions (rows/columns). There the memory for the floats is dynamically allocated and filled with zeros. The specified number of floats is read for each row. If data is missing, a message is written to stderr. The number of rows is returned. The data is then simply output to the console in main, taking the dimensions into account. Finally, the dynamically assigned data is released.

**Further iterations**

The code could be further improved, e.g. the file name should be a function parameter. You should check whether the floats can be read or whether there are conversion errors. But this code could still be a good starting point.

Comment: Thankyou for your answer and an alternative way to approach this. Are structs the standard way of passing large matrices of data? As much as i was wondering why my attempt at a solution didn't work, I'm also interested in what way a C programmer would approach this task? Thanks

Comment: It depends. Normally you work with dynamic matrices in C with a pointer to floats. If the number of rows and columns is known at compile time, you can also specify a two-dimensional array. But as soon as you pass this to a function, you have a pointer to floats again. I did my first iteration with the structure only because I saw some variables named CA, P and V in your code. Here was the thought that it might be more readable to access the column values of each row with their names (CA, P, V). But maybe I misinterpreted the intention.

Comment: ok thankyou, i will concentrate my understanding on pointers then if that is the norm. The structs method does exactly what i want though! So thankyou

Comment: note - I accepted GerhardH's answer as it fixed the code that i had, and that you suggested in the comments is more akin to what would usually be done. However, in MATLAB structs are used and was something i was going to look into and this example does that perfectly. so your answer is extremely useful. Thanks for replying